# Сказуемое в единственном числе?

Tags: сказуемые, единственное-множественное-число

Требуе(ю)тся замена и модернизация оборудования.

Answer (score 2):

*Требуется замена и модернизация оборудования.*

При прямом порядке главных членов предложения (сказуемое следует за однородными подлежащими) обычно употребляется форма множественного числа сказуемого, при обратном порядке (сказуемое предшествует подлежащим) – форма единственного числа. Например:
          а) Жара и засуха стояли более трёх недель; Гул орудий и грохот взрывов расплескались по осенней земле;
          б) До Райского и Марфиньки долетел грубый говор, грубый смех, смешанные голоса, внезапно притихшие… (Гончаров); Появилась ломота во всех членах и мучительная головная боль (Тургенев); Нёсся тяжелый топот кованых сапог и крикливые бабьи взвизги… (Серафимович); По земле, истомлённой в зное, разливалась свежесть, прохлада и неизъяснимая лёгкость… (Солоухин); Хорошо работала связь и комендантские службы.

У нас обратный порядок.

Указанные положения не носят категорического характера: постпозитивное сказуемое может стоять в форме единственного, а препозитивное – в форме множественного числа (особенно часто в технической литературе).

Форма множественного числа препозитивного сказуемого подчеркивает множественность предметов, например: Слышатся кашель и стук (Чехов); Снаружи были слышны визг, лай и вой (Арсеньев); От ветхого барака в темноту леса нырнули конь и всадник (Н. Островский). Обычно такая форма согласования бывает, когда подлежащие обозначают лиц, например: …Арестованы Букин, Самойлов, Сомов и ещё пятеро (Горький). Но если сказуемое выражено глаголом бытия или состояния, то оно может ставиться в форме единственного числа, например: Кроме неё, в комнате находился её муж да ещё некто Увар Иванович Стахов… (Тургенев) (играет роль присоединительный характер второго подлежащего).

Answer (score 1):

**Требуется замена и модернизация оборудования.**

Препозиция сказуемого  – это только один из факторов в пользу выбора ед. числа, но в данном случае **он не является решающим.** В приведенном примере более важно  **смысловое единство однородных подлежащих**.

Розенталь: [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_08](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_08)

Форма единственного числа сказуемого предпочитается **при смысловой близости однородных подлежащих**, например:
1)      сказуемое предшествует подлежащим: На стене висела винтовка и высокая казацкая шапка (Пушкин);

**Примеры использования формы мн. числа:**

Это в первую очередь драма, в которой от актеров **требуются** мужество и настоящая серьезная душевная затрата. [ «Эксперт», 2015]

Сегодня наряду со скоростью от производителя **требуются** еще и гибкость, отзывчивость к нуждам клиента...  «Эксперт», 2014]

Для кардинального изменения ситуации **требуются** масштабная реиндустриализация страны и налаживание комплексной системы стимулирования производства... «Эксперт», 2014]